# How to get a URL string parameter outside of doGet?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a `doGet` method in my Google Apps Script. I pass in a `folderId` parameter in the URL, and I can access it inside of the `doGet` method using the first parameter, in the fashion of `e.parameters.folderId`.

However, my Google Apps Script uploads a file, and I want this parameter to be available to the `upload` method, which my page calls when it tries to upload the file:

```
<button onclick="google.script.run.upload(this.parentNode);">ok</button>
```

I tried to pass it in as a second parameter to this method, but then I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Forms with file inputs must be the only parameter.
  at ...
```

How can I access the `folderId` value from inside the `upload` method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lots of ways. Store it in script as a PropertiesService / CacheService item, store it client side and add it to the form before sending, change your approach and make the user pick the destination after upload, etc.

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks! I ended up using PropertiesService. If you add a more comprehensive answer, I don't mind accepting it.